# What is used to create animated screenshots (as seen on atom packages)

Tags: screenshot, animated-gif, atom-editor

More and more I'm seeing apis or plugins pages with animated gifs, for example the atom packages seem to do that a lot.

See https://atom.io/packages/terminal-status or https://atom.io/packages/mocha-test-runner)

So what tools and workflow is being used to create this animated gifs? (last time I tried it, was quite an heavy process)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found the answer in the Atom Discuss list [What gif creator is atom team using?](https://discuss.atom.io/t/what-gif-creator-is-atom-team-using/1272)

They seem to use http://www.cockos.com/licecap

Answer (score 0):

**[Peek](https://github.com/phw/peek)** is a simple Linux alternative.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:peek-developers/stable
sudo apt update
sudo apt install peek
```